# Are these questions better suited to SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

[Software, script or a tool to automate managing which tests to run](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5644/software-script-or-a-tool-to-automate-managing-which-tests-to-run)

[When unit test fail, show the related file changes from git repo](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/when-unit-test-fail-show-the-related-file-changes-from-git-repo)

I honestly don't remember why I thought they'd go here,
because reading them now I think I'm more asking for a ***way*** to do those things,
rather than asking for particular tools or softwares, which although necessary to achieve the goal are not really at the center of the question.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thats one of the tricky things about SR - we *do* have a natural overlap with Superuser (and well, most of the generalist, and OS specific sites).

I think a good way to approach the problem on hand is to look at how software recommendation questions ought to be asked on SU, as opposed to SR.

Yonking from my answer on MSU

> I'm trying to search for specific text fields in a directory, but only
>   in .txt files - I've tried the following approaches (blah blah blah)
>   but they had these specific problems (blah blah blah). I'm looking for
>   an outcome thats like (foo bar baz). I run yoyodyne OS, and my system has a rocketdyne hardware text search accelerator I'd like to be able to use. How would I do this?

Is a better 'software rec' question for SU - you're focusing on a problem, mention solutions you have tried and what's the outcome you want.

> I need a tool for searching for specific text fields in a directory,
>   but only in .txt files
>
> - I need it to work in yoyodyne OS
> - It needs to be free as in beer
> - Since I'm have a rocketdyne hardware text search accelerator, I'd prefer to have support for this but its optional

In a sense, a good SR question is a laundry list of features. You're looking for a *tool* to solve your problem, as opposed to a solution solved by a tool. Your features narrow down the possible answers to avoid excessive listification.

Both of your questions are really in the fuzzy grey line between the sites IMO, and ought to be fine here.